# How to redirect a child component function into an child function in c++?

Tags: c++

Hi I'm new on the platform (and I'm trully sorry for my bad english).
I'm trying to reduce the number of calls of a display by grouping them in a big Display function in a minigame.

Let me be more clear : I've got a display function in my sprite file

```
  void SpriteComponent::Display(const Timing& timing)
  {
    impl->spriteSheet->Bind(impl->vertexBuffer, impl->indexBuffer);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, (GLsizei) impl->Indices.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, nullptr);
    impl->spriteSheet->Unbind();
  }
```

that I moved into an other Display function like this

```
  void LayerComponent::Display(const Timing& timing)
  {
    auto layerSprites = ListSprites(Owner().shared_from_this());
    if (layerSprites.empty())
    {
      return;
    }

    auto spriteSheet = gsl::at(layerSprites, 0)->GetSpriteSheet();
    Ensures(spriteSheet.Ready());
    
    auto spriteVertexBuffer = gsl::at(layerSprites, 0)->GetSpriteVertex();
    auto spriteIndexBuffer = gsl::at(layerSprites, 0)->GetSpriteIndex();
    auto spriteIndiceSize = gsl::at(layerSprites, 0)->GetSpriteSizeIndices();
    spriteSheet->Bind(spriteVertexBuffer, spriteIndexBuffer);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, (GLsizei) spriteIndiceSize, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, nullptr);
    spriteSheet->Unbind();
  }
}
```

From what I understood (because it's not my code, this is an exercice that I have to do),

SpriteComponent and LayerComponent are children of some other class.
I tried to render all of this stuff, but there is only the half of the displayed game.
I tried to remove the display function of SpriteComponent, but I get a hundred errors because this function is used everywhere in the game.

My question is : Is there any solution to get the SpriteComponent display to redirect on the LayerComponent display ?

If you want addtionnal informations of LayerComponent :

```
  class LayerComponent : public VisualComponent
  {
  public:
    static constexpr auto Type = "Layer";

    LayerComponent(Entity& owner) : Component(owner) {}

    void Display(const Timing& timing) override;
  };
```

Thank you in advance for your answer :)

Comment: I am trying to understand your problem. You want the call `SpriteComponent::Display()` to call `LayerComponent::Display()`? Is `SpriteComponent` a child of `LayerComponent`?

Comment: Hey ! No they are both children from a class called `VirtualComponent` wich is a Virtual class. And yes I'd like `SpriteComponent::Display()` to call `LayerComponent::Display()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I've understood enough to produce a fine answer. So,

> Is there any solution to get the SpriteComponent display to redirect on the LayerComponent display?

Yes, if you can inject those `SpriteComponent`s (create an object and pass it to external code). Create a `FakeSpriteComponent` which is-a `SpriteComponent` and `override` its `Display()` to actually call the `LayerComponent`'s version (or whichever you need):

```
class FakeSpriteComponent: public SpriteComponent {
    std::reference_wrapper<LayerComponent> redirect;
public:
    FakeSpriteComponent(SpriteComponent sprite, LayerComponent& layer)
    : SpriteComponent{std::move(sprite)}, redirect{layer} {}
    void Display(const Timing& timing) const override { redirect.get().Display(timing); }
};
```

Now, at the point of injection (which probably looks like `auto foo(std::unique_ptr<SpriteComponent>) { ... }`) replace current `foo(std::make_unique<SpriteComponent>(sprite))` call with `foo(std::make_unique<FakeSpriteComponent>(sprite, layerToRedirect))`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I'm trying to solve this by using it... What is the `SpriteComponent{std::move(sprite)}, redirect{layer} {}` line ?

Comment: @S3yll it's *member initializer list* (note the "**:**") used to call a specific constructor of a member field / base class, see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor.

Comment: @S3yll and `{}` at the end of it is just an empty constructor. Syntax: `class-name(params) : member-initializer-list { constructor }`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to passing_through's answer, I just had to add a Constructor to my `SpriteComponent`with a private `std::optional<std::reference_wrapper<LayerComponent>> redirect = std::nullopt;` property wich I just had to redirect it using the `redirect.get().Display(timing);` line (into the constructor) without creating a new class